# В чём отличие ПОДОБЛАСТИ от ОГРАНИЧЕННОГО КОНТЕКСТА?

Tags: ddd

Читаю книгу "Реализация методов предметно-ориентированного проектирования" Вон Вернон и не понимаю чем отличаются понятия *подобласть* и *ограниченный контекст*?

Сначала автор рисует запутанную схему, в которой одновременно фигурируют и *ограниченные контексты* и *подобласти*, при этом они ещё и взаимодействуют друг с другом, мало того, некоторые *ограниченные контексты* вмещают в себя несколько *подобластей*, и наоборот.

Дальше автор говорит, что вообще-то *подобласть* относится к *пространству задач*, а *ограниченный контекст* к *пространству решений* (реализации в коде) и упоминает, что хорошо когда

*1 подобласть = 1 ограниченный контекст*

но бывает иначе (как я описал выше).

Но как эти 2 понятия вообще могут пересекаться в контексте одного примера (схемы/диаграммы), если они из разных пространств?

Такое чувство, что автор сам не до конца понимает разницу. Прошу помочь разобраться, если можно на каком-нибудь простом примере, в чем концептуальная разница между этими двумя понятиями, и почему, со слов автора, они вообще могут взаимодействовать, если они в разных плоскостях лежат?

Comment: а где именно эта схема?

Comment: 95 страница, заголовок "ПРЕДМЕТНЫЕ ПОДОБЛАСТИ и ОГРАНИЧЕННЫЕ КОНТЕКСТЫ в действии". Эта схема по контексту книги представлена как начальное, не самое удачное решение, разбор этого решения идёт непосредственно в тексте главы, там постоянно смешиваются понятия _ограниченного контекста_ и _подобласти_, я никак не могу понять посыл автора на этот счёт.

В конечном счёте, конечно, он говорит что нужно стремиться что-бы 1 _подобласть_ = 1 _ограниченный контекст_, но с оговорками что так бывает не всегда, и вот как понять и определить эти _не всегда_? Какие вопросы задать? На что обратить внимание?

Comment: Надо понимать, автор считает, что **хорошо**, это когда *каждой задаче* соответствует *одно решение* (алгоритм? код?), а также это *одно решение* применяется для *одной задачи*. Наверное, таким образом он расуждает о правильной декомпозиции

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на основе написанного в вопросе. Книгу не читал.

> и почему, со слов автора, они вообще могут взаимодействовать, если они
>   в разных плоскостях лежат?

Обратим внимание на определение данных понятий:

> подобласть относится к пространству задач, а ограниченный контекст к
>   пространству решений (реализации в коде)

Отсюда получаем ответ про возможность их взаимодействия: у задач (подобласть) есть решения (ограниченный контекст).

Теперь по поводу того, кто что может в себя вмещать.

Одно и тоже решение, можно применять для разного рода задач, например способом грубой силы (подбор), и наоборот, разными способами можно решить одну задачу (привет Perl подход).

Answer (score 1):

*Подобласть* это термин описывающий единицу деления предметной области в моделировании. И используется для разбиения вашей предметной области.

*Ограниченный контекст* эта техническая реализация подоблости. Например как отдельного приложения в проекте или как микросервиса.
То есть по большому счету это одно и тоже только в разных предметных областях свои термин.

В моделирование говорим подобласть. В кодирование говорим ограниченный контекст.

Что касательно сотвествия подобластей и ограниченных контекстов. Тут как всегда нет серебрянной пули и поэтому автор дает рекомендацию 1 к 1, но бывают случаи когда конкретный заказчик в своем бизнесе требует сильной согласованности между данными и система должна следить за инвариантами между сущностями из двух разных подобластей. Тогда мы можем объеденить эти подобласти в один ограниченный контекст. Но в такой ситуации стоит внимательно проверять согласованность и конфлиты терминов единого языка для этих подобластей.